# Comparison of spaces of global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given two divisors $D$ and $D'$ on a suitable variety $V/K$.

Suppose that $D\leq D'$,

we have for the spaces of global sections:

$$\mathcal{L}(D)=\{f\in K^*(V)|D+div(f)\geq 0\}\cong \Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D))$$
and

$$\mathcal{L}(D')=\{f\in K^*(V)|D'+div(f)\geq 0\}\cong \Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D'))$$

We have quite obviously that if $D\leq D'$, $\mathcal{L}(D)\subset\mathcal{L}(D')$, but then can we moreover compare $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D))$ and $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D'))$ that is for example

if $D\leq D'$ do we have $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D))\subset\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D'))$?

Comment: Let $E=D'-D$. Then $E$ is effective by hypothesis and we have a short exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O}(-D'+D) \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_E \to 0$. Now tensor this by $\mathcal{O}(D')$ and take global sections.